# Total badges counter

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page

I have just noticed the Badges counter which is somewhat confusing;

> [image]

Yes I have taken this snap from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s profile. I am sure you will be surprised to see this. He has a total of 7387 badges but the counter is showing only 552 badges.

Now, I know what this counter is indicating.

**552 Badges:** It indicates the type of badges he has earned. So it doesn't matter if he has gotten a particular badge multiple times.

### My Suggestion:

There should be a title which indicates this, like one of the following:

- Total 7387 badges
- 552 unique badge
- Total 7387 badges, 552 unique badges

Comment: Crikey, he's looking a bit skint for badges on SF, he needs more effort there...

Comment: And we might need to create a platinum Great Answer badge specially for him, to be awarded when he hits 100 gold GA badges.

Comment: +1 this also confused me once.

Comment: It's always confusing for new users. Nice suggestion.

Comment: @Jehof Let's hope you will not be confused once it's defined as #StatusCompleted

Comment: @PareshMayani now i know that its not the total count :-)

Comment: @Jehof Yeh its fine but let's hope it will be clear.

Comment: I wonder there is still no update even after bounty, no moderators has tried to look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature-request has already been implemented.

[image]